# add dynamic of jpanel depending on database using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm developing an app in which I need to add a jpanel to the jframe whenever there is a line on a certain table on my database. The problem is that I made the interface I want with netbeans, but it looks like it's static, I don't find where to use the while loop on my code. This is the code: the jpanel that I want to add dynamically called `list_ligne.get(i)`

```
  javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
                    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
                    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(idPapier_lb)
                                    .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                                    .addComponent(titre_lb)
                                    .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                                    .addComponent(proprietaire_lb)
                                    .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                                    .addComponent(lien_lb)
                                    .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                                    .addComponent(confidentialite_lb))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addContainerGap()
                                    .addComponent(list_lignes.get(2), javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addContainerGap())
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(304, 304, 304)
            .addComponent(ajouter)
            .addGap(85, 85, 85)
            .addComponent(deconnexion)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    );
                    layout.setVerticalGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(idPapier_lb)
                                    .addComponent(titre_lb)
                                    .addComponent(proprietaire_lb)
                                    .addComponent(lien_lb)
                                    .addComponent(confidentialite_lb))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(list_lignes.get(2), javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 99, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(ajouter)
                                        .addComponent(deconnexion))
                                    .addContainerGap())
                        );
                pack();
```

Image of desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem: the GroupLayout layout manager, which I believe NetBeans code generation uses as its default layout, is rather rigid and doesn't easily accept addition of new components at runtime.

Solution: don't have your receiving container use GroupLayout but rather have it use one of the more flexible layouts that allow addition of other components such as GridLayout or BoxLayout. Note that you can **tell** NetBeans GUI builder that this the layout that you want one of your containers to use.

As an aside, I wonder if what you really want to do is to add a row to a JTable.

---

**Edit**
regarding your comment:

> i didn't want to use JTable, it's like a formular (i wanted to add an image of it but they didn't let me) but how do i tell netbeans that i want to use GridLayout or BoxLayout rather than GroupLayout?

I don't use NetBeans or code generation, but if you add a JPanel to your GUI, one that is needed to hold your additional components, I am sure that if you right-click that JPanel, you'll have ability to change its properties including that of its layout manager. There are also other ways that NetBeans allows you to change the properties of the components it is creating, and so you will want to look into that.

Comment: i didn't want to use JTable, it's like a formular (i wanted to add an image of it but they didn't let me) but how do i tell netbeans that i want to use GridLayout or BoxLayout rather than GroupLayout ?

Comment: @MohamedTabti: Please see the edit to my answer. Also please add a link to your image and we'll likely be able to add it for you.

Comment: there is the link https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10570271_1540455382852841_8035841867543573039_n.jpg?oh=ccfc35360194616a60b65f95bcb248f7&oe=5484E19C&__gda__=1419654051_ecd7992eac1e42ca099d3327b247d8ef 
I'm looking for the Layout thing that you told me

Comment: @MohamedTabti: OK, thanks, I've added your image to your question. Will your output ultimately have several rows the JPanel that you've shown? Or will it show only one row? If the former, a JTable could still possibly work, since JTable rows can show buttons. If the latter, then perhaps you don't want to dynamically add a JPanel but rather fill the component fields of an existing JPanel with new data when needed.